# Group row id for all unique rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I would like to generate group row id for each unique rows. Any hint or suggestion would be helpful. I am using SQL Server 2017.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the windowed function `ROW_NUMBER()` as shown below:

```
Select col1
, col2
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1, col2) [Group ID]
from <YourTableName>
```

[image]

[Db<>Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e7c4fe6ea951fb852416f40971a2a097)

Answer (score 1):

For your Case `ROW NUMBER` Function and use `PARTITION` by Column Names

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (Partition By COL1 ORDER BY COL1)  from @T
```